# Solution prevents people who do not have a key from downloading firmware to the MCU

Tags: security, embedded, mcu

I am working with a board which ready to be sold. I received a task: Can a layer of security be created to prevent everyone else, except us from downloading firmware to our MCU on this board.
My initial exploration led me to consider the implementation of Secure Boot as a potential solution. Secure Boot would effectively disallow the reading or downloading of firmware by leveraging a customized bootloader. However, it became apparent that this approach has a potential vulnerability. Even with Secure Boot in place, an individual could potentially reinstall a new bootloader and subsequently download their own firmware onto our board. This raised concerns about the possibility of unauthorized use of our hardware for unintended purposes.

Consequently, I am actively seeking a comprehensive solution that not only prevents unauthorized firmware downloads but also safeguards against the installation of alternative bootloaders. The overarching goal is to ensure the exclusivity of our hardware for its intended purpose. I am keen to explore any viable options or strategies that may address these security challenges. Is it possible?

Comment: The solution to this isn't likely a programming one. But rather "mould in the whole PCB", seal the product or such. Notably it's quite a painful project to reverse engineer a somewhat complex product and then replace the MCU program. The effort required isn't likely something that a random "overly interested" person would be willing to spend, so we are rather talking about illegal actions taken by a company/terrorists. You'll have to clarify why that is a risk in your particular product.

Comment: @Lundin I'm working with a product related to car tracking. It must comply with the regulations of road traffic laws. The firmware, which can be changed, can cause serious consequences. In the worst-case scenario, secret information like PCB drawings, device imei,... may be leaked by developer. If there is a key that only trusted people can know to lock firmware downloading function, it will be more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The overarching goal is to ensure the exclusivity of our hardware for its intended purpose. [...] Is it possible?

Yes, this is possible as you suggest. Select your MCU wisely.

Practically every current MCU can be protected against read-out. But for many MCU families you cannot stop someone with direct access to the hardware to replace the firmware with whatever she wants after a full erasure.

In these cases you can put some secrets into *your* firmware that locks unauthorized devices out of your services. An alternative firmware will not know this secret.

Some MCU families have an additional protection against a complete erasure *without provision by the running firmware*:

- (Kudos to pmacfarlane!) STM32s can be set so the JTAG interface is permanently disabled and the flash cannot be changed. (RDP level 2 in ST's terminology.)
- Another example is the LPC1100 family of NXP in code readout protection level 3 (CRP3).

Comment: In addition to your answer: There may be some ways to integrate hardware solutions which require some pins to be set or DAC outputs at a determined value to enable some hardware functionality. Without the correct values and pins set, the hardware wouldn't be functional. Though with some reverse engineering one could still make it possible to find the requirements to run the board and write software for it.

Comment: @Ian Sure. As an attacker I would not replace the firmware before I understand how the system works. We are not talking about script kiddies here. :-D

Comment: Exactly this. If one decides to 'abuse' hardware, it's most likely they _know_ how to find out how hardware works. I've seen the other way around. MCU with firmware refused to boot on a different board due to some checks on hardware (ADC value at determined level to detect the board type and authenticity). This was meant to prevent resoldering the MCU to a non official board. Still no real protection to abuse anything..

Comment: STM32s can be set so the JTAG interface is permanently disabled and the flash cannot be changed. (RDP level 2 in ST's terminology.)

Comment: @pmacfarlane Thanks for pointing that out! It proves my answer wrong, so I will delete it shortly. You might want to write an alternative answer.

Comment: Because an accepted answer cannot be deleted, I edited it to show the current knowledge. Feel free to enhance it further!